# Error L6242E: Cannot link object as its attributes are incompatible with the image attribute

Tags: linker, embedded, static-libraries, ds-5

I'm using the ARM DS-5 Eclipse IDE.

I'm attempting to link 2 projects (myProj and myProj_bsp). The first one is built on ARM-6 Compiler, meanwhile the second one is built on ARM-5 Compiler. Therefore, I've got the build errors: L6242E cannot link object as its attributes are incompatible with the image attributes. In the console window, I've got the following errors:

....wchart-16 clashes with wchart-32.

....packed-enum clashes with enum_is_int.

I think that the error is due to the data type mismatch between 2 compilers.

Could anybody tell me how to fix this issue ??

Answer (score 0):

ARM5(armcc) and ARM6(armclang) compilers are totally different compilers. The error is due to the linker detecting different sizes of wchar and enums in both objects being linked. The objects being linked should have same size for wchar and enums. This can be done by passing --wchar32 and --enum_as_int to ARM5 compiler which treats wchar as 32 bit size and enums also of 32bit. More details on the error can be found in below link.

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0483/g/frequently-asked-questions-and-troubleshooting/gnu-linker-or-armlink-report-conflicts-between-wchar-t-types